# PowerShell: Get registry key name given sub-key name & value

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I'm trying to return a registry key name given sub-key name & value. For instance, if exists:

```
HKLM:\Software\key1\home1 home_val=C:\dir1
HKLM:\Software\key2\home2 home_val=C:\dir2
```

I want to be able to return the key name that has sub-key=home_val=C:\dir1

I'm ALMOST there but can't figure out how to return the key name. I've come up with the following:

```
Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\key*' -Name HOME_VAL | Select-Object -Property 'C:dir1'
```

Comment: The subkey has a PSParentPath property with the parent key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code gives me this error...

> Get-ItemPropertyValue : Property HOME_VAL does not exist at path HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\key1

...when it encounters a key without a `HOME_VAL` value.

This works for me to get the full key path...

```bsh
PS> $filterValueName = 'home_val'
PS> $filterValueData = 'C:\dir1'
PS> Get-ChildItem -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\key*' -Recurse `
        | Where-Object { ($_ | Get-ItemProperty -Name $filterValueName).$filterValueName -eq $filterValueData } `
        | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Name'
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\key1\home1
```

That will enumerate all descendant keys beneath any `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\key*` keys, selecting those that have a value named `home_val` with data `C:\dir1` and extracting their `Name` property.  If you want the key name instead of its path you can select the `PSChildName` property instead.

Comment: Sweet! This works a treat. I knew that when making a registry value a PSCustomObject, you had to call it twice to get a property but couldn't figure out how to return the value I wanted. Piping "Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Name'" was what I was missing. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this right, the home_val's are right under the key*'s?  If it's farther down, you can recurse and ignore the errors.  "$_" has to be piped in, because the string version of the key isn't usable as a command argument.  Either use simplematch with select-string, or double the backslashes, because it's a regex.  Get-childitem doesn't really return the registry values and data.  It's an illusion of the display.

```
new-item hklm:\software\key1
new-item hklm:\software\key2
new-itemproperty hklm:\software\key1 home_val -value c:\dir1
new-itemproperty hklm:\software\key2 home_val -value c:\dir2

get-childitem -recurse hklm:\software\key* | 
  where { $_ | get-itemproperty | select-string c:\dir1 -simplematch }


    Hive: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software


Name                           Property
----                           --------
key1                           home_val : C:\dir1
```

Or this way:

```
get-childitem -r hklm:\software\key* | get-itemproperty | 
  where { $_.home_val -match 'c:\\dir1' }


home_val     : c:\dir1
PSPath       : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software\key1\home1
PSParentPath : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software\key1
PSChildName  : home1
PSProvider   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry
```

Comment: Thanks @js2010. Your solution also works and helped fill in some of the "holes" in my PowerShell coding foundation. I'm relatively new to PowerShell and seeing well written/concise code really helps me come up to speed.

Comment: Yw.  Working with powershell and the registry isn't the most straightforward.